# solar panel charging battery

Tags: batteries, solar-cell, charging, 12v

I'm looking to power a wireless security camera from a 12v 1.4a battery being charged by a 12v solar panel. question is will i over amp camera from solar panel? camera has rating of 12v .5a" don't know output of solar panel yet"

Comment: I'm concerned about someone building a battery charger who doesn't understand that a load cannot be "over amp"ed.

Answer (score 1):

The solar panel will charge the battery, and the camera will draw power from the battery.

The camera will draw what it needs when in use. So since it's a 1.4A battery, the camera is only going to use 0.5A of the available current and keep the rest to charge the battery when the solar panel is active.

See also: [Using a 12V battery while simultaneously charging via solar panel](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/79075/using-a-12v-battery-while-simultaneously-charging-via-solar-panel?rq=1)